# Separate string by comma , data coming from JSON

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I am facing the following issue,

I have parsed data from a server and I need all keys to be put into the arrays.

```
(
"shopping|TD|Shopping|TD|customer/shopping_icon.png",
    "salon_spa|TD|Salon & Spa|TD|customer/salon_icon.png",
)
```

These are the keys I'm getting from the server, now I want to put them into an Array.

I have tried using component separated by string but that always crashes the app.

```
NSMutableArray *allKeysArray =[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
[allKeysArray addObject: [deals allKeys]];
NSLog(@" all keys --%@",allKeysArray);
NSMutableString *string=[[NSMutableString alloc]init];
string =[allKeysArray objectAtIndex:0];
NSLog(@"string--%@",string);
arr =[string componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
```

The app crashes saying component separated by string is Terminating app due to uncaught exception

> 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[_]: unrecognized selector
>   sent to instance 0x75b8dd0'

Comment: wt is displayed in string ????

Comment: string--(
    "shopping|TD|Shopping|TD|customer/shopping_icon.png",
    "salon_spa|TD|Salon & Spa|TD|customer/salon_icon.png",
)

Comment: If that first string is supposed to be JSON, it's definitely not. If you have control over the server-side code returning a valid JSON array would be the best solution. If you don't, I wouldn't trust anything that returns that and claims it's JSON.

Comment: yeah its JSON response coming from the server side. 
"fitness|TD|Fitness|TD|customer/fitness_icon.png" =     (
                {
            actualCost = "3500.00";
            address = "SCO-7, 2";
            city = mohn;
            dealCode = "BGS-005";
            dealId = 826;
}
)

this is how its coming , now i want to take all keys in a array seprated by comma

Comment: which string u want do to comma sapareted ??

Comment: "fitness|TD|Fitness|TD|customer/fitness_icon.png"

this one , its an key for the JSON object , so i want all keys to be in array seprated by Comma

Comment: Where do you see any commas in that string? I don't see any. You can't separate it by commas, because there aren't any. That should be common sense. But have a good eagle-eyed look at the string. It seems to be a | separated string... On the other hand, someone is taking that whole string as the key, so are you really sure you want to pull the key apart?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your code from ....

```
[allKeysArray addObject: [deals allKeys]];
```

as like this...

```
[allKeysArray addObjectsFromArray: [deals allKeys]];
```

This will solve your problem...